# Mint 18.1 - A whole lot of "Soliciting pool server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Tags: linux-mint, syslog, ntpd

I was looking in syslog to look into an audio issue and I see a hell of a lot of the Soliciting pool server  ntp daemon messages. I've run other linux in past and never recall seeing so many ntp log messages. Is this due to a new network issue perhaps, is it common for Mint, is there a way to shush them if it is "common"?

I've changed carriers and router hardware since those days, so I do not rule out something in my net. I have no problems accessing internet or playing online games etc.

Comment: I'm new to this, someone "downvoted" the question - could you please provide feedback so I know what I did wrong or why it is not a correct question or location for question or?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can see a couple problems with your question that might have turned someone off: Title with a very mild curse word and not very descriptive. Mint (sometimes seen as a novice distro). A 'problem' that doesn't seem like it's actually a problem (what issues is this causing, if any?).

Comment: I can see what you mean from the title. I was being a bit too flippant - really more like "ironic" considering I am 52 and never use that word although I read it all the time these days ;) (for the record, I would have written it worse as "A hell of a lot of ..." had I not done as I did. Forgive my Catholic NYer lack of sensibilities ;P I will refrain from such usage going forward (earnestly meant btw - not being sarcastic.)

Comment: For the record, the original title was: Mint 18.1 - Hella lot of “Soliciting pool server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx”  - I changed it so as not to offend in case it did some.

Comment: @etskinner And thanks for the feedback on what it might have been. My feedback to original downvoter is a brief sentence on "bad title/doing it's job/etc" would go a long way to preventing these Questions in future from those willing to listen, Thanks all.

Comment: FYI, StackExchange does keep edit history, so no need to state things for the record.

Comment: [askubuntu.com: How do I disable ntpd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29663/11522)

Answer (score 11):

The messages mean your ntpd server is looking for more time sources to sync to. Seeing a couple of them is expected, especially after reconnecting to the network after an outage or a restart, but if your ntpd and your network connection are running smoothly, you shouldn't be seeing more than a few per day. If you have several every few minutes, it's likely a problem.

Does your ntpd connect to peers and sync time successfully? You can check for that using `ntpq`. Look at the list of peers in `ntpq -c pe` and the reported stratum and reftime in `ntpq -c rv`. Stratum of 16 means “not synchronized”.

This:

```
user@localhost $ ntpq -c pe
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 de.pool.ntp.org .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
user@localhost $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=c016 leap_alarm, sync_unspec, 1 event, restart,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Tue Jun 20 08:08:18 UTC 2017 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux", leap=11, stratum=16,
precision=-23, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=0.090, refid=INIT,
reftime=00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  7:28:16.000,
clock=dde6bdf4.dec8453b  Fri, Dec 22 2017  0:10:44.870, peer=0, tc=3,
mintc=3, offset=0.000000, frequency=4.981, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=0.000, clk_wander=0.000
```

means your NTP doesn't actually work (in this case because I've just started it up), while this:

```
user@localhost $ ntpq -c pe
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 cz.pool.ntp.org .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
+mail.nettel.cz  195.113.144.201  3 u    4   64  377    5.215   -0.842   0.332
*fedecks.wuji.cz 195.113.144.238  2 u   61   64  377    2.121   -2.005   0.171
-lx.ujf.cas.cz   .GPS.            1 u   62   64  177    2.662   -0.714   0.215
-pyrrha.fi.muni. 195.113.144.238  2 u   63   64  177    7.445   -0.697   0.340
-host-81-200-57- 192.168.3.246    2 u   55   64  177   15.792    0.098   1.160
  cz.inthouse.clo 147.231.2.6      2 u   47   64   17    5.338   -0.266   0.461
user@localhost $ ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sat Jul 29 07:38:14 UTC 2017 (1)",
processor="ppc", system="Linux", leap=00, stratum=2,
precision=-19, rootdelay=2.652, rootdisp=4.409, refid=147.231.100.5,
reftime=dde6be4a.f90912d6  Fri, Dec 22 2017  0:12:10.972,
clock=dde6be4d.12f27b56  Fri, Dec 22 2017  0:12:13.074, peer=10703, tc=6,
mintc=3, offset=-0.387828, frequency=-254.539, sys_jitter=1.572660,
clk_jitter=0.456, clk_wander=0.098
```

means your NTP works correctly.

If it doesn't sync and stays that way for a long time, you likely have a network or configuration problem. Look at `man 5 ntp.conf` for help and at [the NTP.org support page about configuration](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringNTP) for examples. In my case, the reason for the unending “Soliciting pool server” spam was the `nopeer` directive, which has to be off for pool servers.

Answer (score -1):

To me it just seems like NTP is doing its job: requesting time data from NTP servers, then posting that in the syslog. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you, it just seemed like a really egregious amount of detail logging like "hey, I'm doing my job, nothing wrong but I'll check this one next" ever couple seconds to minutes apart.  I switched to Mint this time because it was reviewed well and last I had was Ubuntu which I only barely used for my kid's game servers and my development repositories. Prior to that in early Aughts I was using Gentoo and loving it (I started stage 1 first couple time like a nut since didn't need to really) but I used it less as time got short & then each time I did - I'd spend too much on long emerge catchups

Comment: Forgot to mention in my spammage... I definitely have some sort of network issue that is another issue so won't go into details here (involves "pausing" puttys/terms/ssh etc buffering everything I type until underlying conn is reastablished) so I thought maybe the constant NTPD logs indicated some network connectivity issue due to the quantity involved

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, I (and most people) don't judge people based on distro, but some people do. Probably best do create a separate question for the other network issues you're seeing. While NTP logs might be a good symptom to mention, it doesn't seem to be the problem itself.

Comment: Will do - thanks. Yeah, I tried to mention it only b/c it might be related BUT didn't want toi give more details since I DID read the ask one question per ;) thing (which makes sense) - I just didn't have a benchmark to gauge the amount of ntp "spam" against. Will see after I get to rewiring/testing the other issue - if at same time ntp spam drops. Will update for posterity ;)